# CSS - Mobile website responding strangely?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been developing a website and am currently using media queries for responsiveness. The media queries work perfectly and the website turns mobile in the emulators. (http://mobt.me/2T5i and Chrome's inspect element). On both emulators the site looks exactly how i want it, but then when i view it on my iphone 5 running ios8, its a completely different story. I have included the meta tag and everything but it still behaves weirdly on my phone. I also checked on a friends phone and the same thing happens. You can view the website [here](http://lernereap.com)

This is what it looks like on my phone:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason safari doesn't read your media-queries. I don't know why but, try this kind of media query:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:640px), screen and (max-width:640px) {
    /* styles here */
}
```

TIP: There are some classes that dont work well in safari.

You should do is add these lines to your media query:

```
@media (max-width: 775px) and (min-width: 500px) {
 .item-wrap {
  display:none;
 }
}
```

This will hide your desktop-menu (visible:hidden, doesnt work).

EDIT:

Well, you should check in your head tag. You are loading bootstrap before load jquery, try with this code:

```
<head>

 <title>Third Wave Analytics</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,300italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



<script>
function scroll(){
$('.btnMedio').click(function(event) {
    // Preventing default action of the event
    event.preventDefault();
    // Getting the height of the document
    var n = $('#myCarousel').height() + 20;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: n }, 900);
});
};
$(document).ready(scroll);
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: `display: none;` didn't change anything, and using max-device-width  messed up the navbar for the desktop as well as mobile.

Comment: it still doesn't work, bootstrap shouldnt matter since i didnt use it.

Comment: Sometimes you can have problems if there are errors like that.

Comment: Okey. The last thing that comes to mind is this little change:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">`
If not, try to add 
`type="text/javascript"` to all scripts tags.

Comment: You have several errors in your style.css like:
`Line 11: Delete innecesary }
Line 142: Delete innecesary */
Line 159: Type white space betwen media and (max-width... like this -> media (max-width: 780px){ 
Line 550: Dont forget the white space here:
media screen and(max-dev... -> media screen and (max-dev...`

Comment: If you can check my answer like a usefull answer it would be great. :)